# How do I pass a variable from one If Statement to another If Statement in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, variables

I am attempting to have a variable that is established in one If Statement be able to be passed to another If Statement. This is my test code:

```
if (test-path -path "C:\temp\watcher.txt"){
    $script:NewName = rename-item "C:\temp\watcher.txt" -NewName "C:\temp\date_watcher.txt"  
    }
    else
    {
    Write-host "nothin here boss"
    }
if (test-path -path $script:newname){
    $NewName2 = rename-item $script:newname -NewName "C:\temp\dateSECOND_watcher.txt"
    }
    else
    {
    Write-host "nothin here boss"
    }
```

The first statement works as it should, but it does not recognize the variable in the second statement with the error:

"Test-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null"

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Rename-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-5.1) does not generate any output unless you specify the parameter `-Passthru`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable isn’t getting initialised because Rename-Item doesn’t return an object by default.

Try adding `-PassThru` to it in order to have it return the object you expect.